# Can I consume a web service from an appengine app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an appengine app that I want to use as a front end to some existing web services. How can I consume those WS from my app?

I'm using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [URLFetch API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/).

Comment: That's it. I just need to figure out a way to use SOAP calls

Comment: Just wrap the call in a SOAP envelope then you should be good

Answer (score 1):

In addition to just URLFetch and hand constructing SOAP envelopes, you can also use higher level SOAP libraries like SUDS.  Which can parse WSDL and construct requests for you.  For performance reasons you will want to cache the WSDL. In one project I parse this offline and deploy the optimised code with the application.